I want to widen all the text inside my documents
So I tried this, but I am looking for any one-liner to increase the letter spacing of all the text inside the documents a little bit, without manually using textls. Is it possible?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterspace=150]{microtype}

\begin{document}
\textls[300]{
Normal text.

\textls[200]{Wider text}

 wider text  wider text wider text  wider text wider text  wider text wider text  wider text wider text  wider text wider text  wider text wider text  wider text wider text  wider text

}
\end{document}


Welcome to SE! I think you might be looking for the geometry package, perhaps?

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please extend your code to a minimal working example (MWE). Also make the goal a little clearer. Should the text width be increased by reducing the page margin? Then, as already suggested, the geometry package would be an option.

You can try the \lsstyle switch
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterspace=150]{microtype}

\begin{document}
        Normal text.
        
        \textls[300]{Wider text}
        
        Normal text again
        
        \lsstyle
        wider text  wider text wider text  wider text wider text  wider text wider text  wider text wider text  wider text wider text  wider text wider text  wider text wider text  wider text
\end{document}


To use that style for the whole document, put the \lsstyle at right after begin document.

I edited the MWE, bad copy paste on my part.

thanks it works

@JanakMallik, if you like the answer and it was helpful, please consider upvoting (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the accepted answer (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).
